# trouble retrieving image name from database on product edit and submit

Tags: php, file-upload

i have 1 week trouble finding a solution 
so let me exmaplin 
i have a input type file on a html form
that looks like this

```
     <form action ="MenaxhoProduktet.php?ID=<?php print $_SESSION["ID"]; ?>&Editing=<?php print $Editing; ?>"method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and an input type file which looks like this

```
<input class="form-input" type="file"  name="Fotografia"  id="file"  value="<?php print $Fotografia ?>" accept="image/*"/>
```

and i have php code that uploads image to directory saving name on database

```
    if(isset($_FILES['Fotografia']['name'])) 
                $Fotografia = $_FILES['Fotografia']['name'];
                $file_size =$_FILES['Fotografia']['size'];
                $file_tmp =$_FILES['Fotografia']['tmp_name'];
                $file_type=$_FILES['Fotografia']['type'];   
                $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['Fotografia']['name'])));

                $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
                if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
                    $mesazhiGabim ="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
                }
                if($file_size > 2097152){
                $mesazhiKujdes='File size must be excately 2 MB';
                }               
                if(empty($errors)==true){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$Fotografia);
                    echo "Success";
                }
                else
                {
                    print_r($errors);
                }
        }
```

but when i edit the product and i want to change price only i need to upload image again or it will delete the image name from database

how do i prevent this code from deleting image name from database when i edit a product
or how i can change product name or price without having to upload image again and again ...
THanks u so much if u save me from going mad...

Comment: Where is your database code? That is where the issue and solution lie

Comment: Yeah, you should omit the `SET picture = "$file"`-like statement in your UPDATE query when no file was uploaded